# php membersite_config.php page internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, user-accounts, internal-server-error

Hello i am new at this website and i really need your help i am getting an internal server error when trying to access my membersite_config.php file on my website i took this file from this website http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html

This is the script:

```
    <?PHP
    require_once("./include/fg_membersite.php");

    $fgmembersite = new FGMembersite();

    //Provide your site name here
    $fgmembersite->SetWebsiteName('user11.com');

    //Provide the email address where you want to get notifications
    $fgmembersite->SetAdminEmail('user11@user11.com');

    //Provide your database login details here:
    //hostname, user name, password, database name and table name
    //note that the script will create the table (for example, fgusers in this case)
    //by itself on submitting register.php for the first time
    $fgmembersite->InitDB(/*hostname*/'localhost',
                  /*username*/'prasanth',
                  /*password*/'p',
                  /*database name*/'testdb',
                  /*table name*/'fgusers3');

    //For better security. Get a random string from this link: http://tinyurl.com/randstr
    // and put it here
    $fgmembersite->SetRandomKey('qSRcVS6DrTzrPvr');

    ?>
```

Btw the fg_membersite.php that is required is working

Comment: `<?php` instead of `<?PHP` maybe? [Enable PHP error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/) and try again..

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Need more information.  Check the log files - any errors there?

Comment: Can you plz explain to me what do you mean by log files and how do i get them

Answer (score 0):

> $fgmembersite->InitDB(/*hostname*/'localhost',
>                     /*username*/'prasanth',
>                     /*password*/'p',
>                     /*database name*/'testdb',
>                     /*table name*/'fgusers3');

You have to change *username* and *password* fields as you installed in mysql. Here 'Prasanth' and 'p' won't work for you at first i guess. Good luck!